# Cannot find data type blob

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, image

I'm trying to create an image DB, so far I got this from the Internet:

```
CREATE TABLE testblob (
image_id tinyint not null default '0',
image_type varchar(25) not null default '',
image blob not null,
image_size varchar(25) not null default '',
image_ctgy varchar(25) not null default '',
image_name varchar(50) not null default '', 
);
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   Column, parameter, or variable #3: Cannot find data type blob

Comment: You might want to start by removing the trailing comma before ``);`` ...

Comment: Use VARBINARY(MAX) in place of BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[testblob]    Script Date: 7/27/2017 7:53:08 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testblob](
    [image_id] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [image_type] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [image] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [image_size] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [image_ctgy] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [image_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testblob] ADD  DEFAULT ('0') FOR [image_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testblob] ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR [image_type]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testblob] ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR [image_size]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testblob] ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR [image_ctgy]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testblob] ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR [image_name]
GO
```